# Segmentation Fault in my C++ Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm making a solver for the game Flood-It (I think also known as Blobs).  The program compiles and runs fine until the very end . . . I do a final "cout" (and then added the "return 0" with no effect) at the end of my main() function, and it pops up "FloodItSolver.exe has stopped working..."

When I do a "gdb FloodItSolver" and then "r" I end with the following output:

```
Did not complete in 25 turns.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6fc5b222 in libstdc++-6!_ZN9__gnu_cxx18__exchange_and_addEPVii () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
```

That part about "Did not complete" is the last thing I cout.

UPDATE:  Here is the result of issuing the "backtrace" command at gdb:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x6fc5b222 in libstdc++-6!_ZN9__gnu_cxx18__exchange_and_addEPVii () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x6fcbd66e in libstdc++-6!atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#2  0x00401fee in __tcf_2 () at flooditsolver.cpp:9
#3  0x75b3c3e9 in msvcrt!isspace () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#4  0x75b437df in msvcrt!_cexit () from C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
#5  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

It makes no sense because I hit the end of my main()!  Why would it SegFault here?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//  GLOBAL---------------------------------------------------------------------
int rgbPos, scPos, color, grid[14][14];
ifstream file("Floodit.txt");
bool isFlood[14][14];
string line;
//  END GLOBAL-------------------------------------------------------------

//  Function Pool ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
//  HighestBorderCount(), NonFloodColorsLeft(), CanEliminateAColor(), etc...
//  Gather a list of variables you consider when planning your next move, then make a function for it
//  So far I only have HighestBorderCount()

int HighestBorderCount()
{
    int highest=0, returnMe, countColors[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    bool paddedBorder[16][16], border[14][14];
    for(int x=0;x<16;x++) {for(int y=0;y<16;y++) {paddedBorder[x][y]=false;}}
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++) {for(int y=0;y<14;y++) {border[x][y]=false;paddedBorder[x+1][y+1]=isFlood[x][y];}}    // Create copy of isFlood, zero out border[][]
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++) 
    {
        for (int y=0;y<14;y++) 
        {
            if( (!paddedBorder[x+1][y+1]) && (  (paddedBorder[x][y+1]) || (paddedBorder[x+1][y]) || (paddedBorder[x+2][y+1]) || (paddedBorder[x+1][y+2])    )   ) border[x][y]=true;
            if(border[x][y])
            {
                switch(grid[x][y])
                {
                    case 0:
                        countColors[0]++;
                        cout<<"0 on border\n";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        countColors[1]++;
                        cout<<"1 on border\n";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        countColors[2]++;
                        cout<<"2 on border\n";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        countColors[3]++;
                        cout<<"3 on border\n";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        countColors[4]++;
                        cout<<"4 on border\n";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        countColors[5]++;
                        cout<<"5 on border\n";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x=0;x<6;x++) if(countColors[x]>highest) highest=countColors[x];
    for(int x=0;x<6;x++) if(countColors[x]==highest) returnMe=x;
    return returnMe;
}

//  End Function Pool ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

void Pivot(int x, int y)
{
    if(x>0)
    {
        if((grid[x-1][y]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x-1][y]==false))
        {
            isFlood[x-1][y]=true;
            Pivot(x-1, y);
        }
    }
    if(x<14)
    {
        if((grid[x+1][y]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x+1][y]==false))
        {
            isFlood[x+1][y]=true;
            Pivot(x+1, y);
        }
    }
    if(y>0)
    {
        if((grid[x][y-1]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x][y-1]==false))
        {
            isFlood[x][y-1]=true;
            Pivot(x, y-1);
        }
    }
    if(y<14)
    {
        if((grid[x][y+1]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x][y+1]==false))
        {
            isFlood[x][y+1]=true;
            Pivot(x, y+1);
        }
    }
}

void Flood(int FloodColor)
{
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++) {for (int y=0;y<14;y++) {if (isFlood[x][y]) Pivot(x,y);}} //  This run tells us what area to include in the flood
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<14;y++)
        {
            if(isFlood[x][y]) grid[x][y]=FloodColor;                                                //  This floods the area
            cout<<grid[x][y]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++) {for (int y=0;y<14;y++) {if (isFlood[x][y]) Pivot(x,y);}} //  This updates the flood area, so we include newly acquired blocks
}

int GetColor(string s)
{
    s=s.substr(0,s.find(","));
    if(s=="237") return 0;              //  PINK == 0
    else if(s=="96") return 1;          //  PURPLE == 1
    else if(s=="243") return 2;         //  YELLOW == 2
    else if(s=="220") return 3;         //  RED == 3
    else if(s=="70") return 4;          //  BLUE == 4
    else if(s=="126") return 5;         //  GREEN == 5
    else return 6;                              
}

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/)
{
    int input, counter=0;
    for(int x=0;x<14;x++) {for(int y=0;y<14;y++) {isFlood[x][y]=false;}} 
    isFlood[0][0]=true;

    //  GET INPUT
    if(file.is_open()) {while(file.good())  {getline(file, line);}}
    file.close();

    //  POPULATE GRID
    line=line.substr(11);
    for(int x=0;x<196;x++)
    {
        rgbPos=line.find("rgb");
        scPos=line.find("; \">");
        color=GetColor(line.substr(rgbPos+4,scPos-1-(rgbPos+4)));
        grid[x/14][x%14]=color;
        line=line.substr(scPos+3);
    }

    bool complete=false;
    bool floodCheck;
    while((!complete)&&(counter<25))
    {
        counter++;
        floodCheck=true;
        //cout<<"Highest border count: "<<HighestBorderCount()<<endl;
        //cin>>input;
        Flood(HighestBorderCount());
        for(int y=0;y<14;y++) {for(int z=0;z<14;z++) {if(!isFlood[y][z]) floodCheck=false;}}
        if(floodCheck) complete=true;
    }
    if(complete) {cout<<"Completed in "<<counter<<" turns!";} else {cout<<"Did not complete in 25 turns.";}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely you've already corrupted something, and it's not until the program goes to clean up, and call destructors that it's getting recognized.

Comment: at least a full backtrace from gdb would be much more useful than just the last frame.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gdb, and only found how to do what I did via Google.  What would a full backtrace entail?  At the gdb prompt, what would you like me to type?

Comment: What's the content of `Floodit.txt`?

Comment: the seg fault is comming from libstd++, the only part of libstd++ your using is the file stream (fstream). Your while loop should check for eof, not good. The loop is accessing invalid data in the filestream. also be sure to include <string> if your going to use it. Always include all the std lib headers you need. Never assume one header will drag in another.

Comment: Found the "backtrace" command, updating post...

Comment: @johnathon -- I do file.close() two lines after the //GET INPUT comment

Comment: FloodIt.txt contains a bunch of HTML garbage copied from the web page where Flood-It is hosted.  I can post it if you want?

Comment: At least we can reproduce it locally.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I forgot #include <string> -- It didn't help, though, same results.

Comment: Simplify your code to the point where we can reproduce it.  Sscce.org

Comment: Ok, FloodIt.txt is at http://pastebin.com/pUeh9xKa   [it's all one line of text]

Comment: The usual advice: run the program under `valgrind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error after `main` completes indicates an issue with destruction of the variables in `main` or objects with static storage duration. If you print the backtrace from the debugger you will at least see the type of the object being destroyed when the error occurred.

Comment: Not much (I don't know the platform), but you have much more information. You can move up and down the stack and see the parameters to the functions, and that should be enough to understand what object is being destroyed. As a quick hunch, the only object that has a non-trivial destructor is the `ifstream`, try moving that into `main` to avoid potential order of initialization issues.

Comment: Moving that part into main() did not help.  I will look into the gdb more as you have mentioned.

Comment: And the platform is g++ on Windows 7 64-bit.  Not sure what other info you'd need.

Comment: Beautiful; I went "up" through the "backtrace" and one line stuck out, which was my initialization of string "line" -- I moved that into main() and it ran without a segfault!

Comment: @armani: While there is no reason for that failure (at least apparent to me), note that the least objects with static storage duration that you have, the best. (I.e. avoid globals at all costs)

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
for(int x=0;x<196;x++)
{
    rgbPos=line.find("rgb");
    scPos=line.find("; \">");
    color=GetColor(line.substr(rgbPos+4,scPos-1-(rgbPos+4)));
    grid[x/14][x%14]=color;
    line=line.substr(scPos+3);
}
```

You don't check to see if `find` returns `npos` or not. So you will have screwy indexing into your `string` object.

Also, in `Pivot`:

```
//...
if(x<14)
{
    if((grid[x+1][y]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x+1][y]==false))
    {
        isFlood[x+1][y]=true;
        Pivot(x+1, y);
    }
}
//...
if(y<14)
{
    if((grid[x][y+1]==grid[x][y])&&(isFlood[x][y+1]==false))
    {
        isFlood[x][y+1]=true;
        Pivot(x, y+1);
    }
}
```

You are indexing past the boundary of your `isFlood` array and assigning a value to it.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because that happens early on in my main() code.  I see the other operations run as the program run, plus I had this program working with manual cin input yesterday.  Not sure what I tweaked to cause my current segfault, even changing back to cin input gives me a segfault.

Comment: You're right. What actually happened is that you are overrunning your `isFlood` buffer, and it was corrupting your `line`.

Answer (score 0):

Try building with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind

Comment: @armani, If you're using windows then link with MFC and use `DEBUG_NEW`.

Comment: That's probably too complicated for me.  Don't know what that is, and Googling got me confused.